# pros and cons of air mattress, sleeping pads, folding foam futon, sleeping bag in long layover?

Tags: airports, layovers, gear, sleeping

I have been trying to figure out what is cheaper, lighter and has a long shelf life between an air mattress or/and sleeping bag. The obvious use case is sleeping on the floor when on a long layover but also as an additional comforter for the first night in a strange environment as shared as being defined travel-induced [insomnia](http://www.streetdirectory.com/etoday/drugs-used-for-overcoming-sleeplessness-ewafla.html) or first-night [effect](http://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822(16)30174-9) . In both cases, having familiar smells is supposed to reduce the insomnia and have a more fitful sleep. I looked at http://1source.basspro.com/index.php/component/k2/242-camping-equipment/876-which-is-right-for-you-air-mattress-sleeping-pad-or-cot and https://www.reddit.com/r/Frugal/comments/5m74fo/frugal_bedding_air_mattress_vs_sleeping_bag_vs/ and came across two new options as well - sleeping pads and foam folding futon neither of which I am aware. I am looking for something which is 5'9 or 5'10 but dunno which of these I should be looking at ?

Can somebody list some typical brands and which of these four could/should be used while travelling. Obviously, dimensions and size along with comfort as don't want to cut things unnecessarily when travelling. Most LCC's and even full-service carriers conk out at 25-30 kgs (if they are feeling generous) where clothing takes the most place when you are travelling from a somewhat temperate climate to a more colder one.

There are two places where I hope to use either of those -

a. On the floor of an airport

b. On a cot in a room.

Looking forward to inputs.

Comment: These all serve pretty different purposes (you sleep inside or under a sleeping bag to keep you warm, while you sleep on top of an air mattress or sleeping pad because it's more comfortable than the floor) so they really can't be compared. It's also impossible to answer without knowing where you plan to use these things.

Comment: @ZachLipton have shared more info. hopefully that helps.

Comment: A sleeping bag takes up too much of your carry-on volume.  An air mattress would be better, but still takes up a lot of volume.  Do your flight plans involve that many long layovers that require sleeping in airports?